# Nodejs Twit module error on stopping stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, streaming

I'm using the [Twit module](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) to display a Twitter stream in an AngularJS app. I want to give the option to turn off the stream when the user clicks the stop button.

The script that handles the streaming:

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key        : 'XXX',
    consumer_secret     : 'XXX',
    access_token        : 'XXX',
    access_token_secret : 'XXX'
});

function streamingHashtag(streamBool)
{    
  var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'test' });

  stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
    console.log(tweet);
  });

  stream.on('disconnect',function(disconnectMessage){
    stream.stop();
  });

  if(streamBool == false){
    stream.stop();
    console.log('Stream stopped by user');
  }
}
```

After pressing the button to stop the console outputs the following error and the stream continues:

```
message: "Cannot call method 'abort' of undefined", stack: "TypeError: Cannot call method 'abort' of undefined…es\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:37:5)"}
message: "Cannot call method 'abort' of undefined"
stack: "TypeError: Cannot call method 'abort' of undefined?    at OARequest.stop ([localhost]\node_modules\twit\lib\oarequest.js:110:16)?    at Object.streamingHashtag ([localhost]\server\library\twitter.js:40:10)?    at exports.twitterStream ([localhost]\server\routes\index.js:11:10)?    at callbacks ([localhost]\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)?    at param ([localhost]\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)?    at pass ([localhost]\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)?    at Router._dispatch ([localhost]\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)?    at Object.router ([localhost]\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)?    at next ([localhost]\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)?    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] ([localhost]\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:37:5)"
```

I'm running the latest version (package.json says "version": "1.1.11") and upon investigating I found the stop function in OARequest.js that directs to abort().

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone getting the same error and for future reference let me answer my own question now that I've found the answer. The error stated that there wasn't a method 'abort' on undefined while I was sure I declared the variable.

The error was caused by invoking the function twice, creating a new scope in which the old variable wasn't available. Defining the variable outside the function globally fixed this.